# regex finds only 1 match when splitting on all capital letters

Tags: regex, rust

I'm using the regex crate and attempting to split a string on capital letters. The regex expression I'm using is `([A-Z][a-z]+)` which, on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/359Vu4/1) is confirmed to work as expected.

My function is simple:

```rust
pub fn format_str_with_regex(str_to_format: String) {
    let re = regex::Regex::new(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)").expect("Unable to create regex pattern");
    let fields = re.captures(&str_to_format).expect("Unable to get capture groups");

    println!("{:?}", fields);
}
```

I've passed in various strings such as "Hello", "HelloWorld", "MyNameIsMrSmith" and instead of getting multiple captures I just get the entire string passed back to me.

For instance, if I use `println!("{:?}", fields.get(1));` I get "Hello", "HelloWorld", "MyNameIsMrSmith" and if I use `println!("{:?}", fields.get(2));` I just get `None`.

Comment: Your regex has only got 1 capturing group, so it is logical you get None when you try to access Group 2. You mean to match *multiple pattern occurrences*, not groups within one single match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`captures`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.7/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures) gives you captures from the leftmost match.

It sounds like you are interested in all findings matching your regex. Maybe [`find_iter`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.7/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.find_iter)is what you're after:

```
pub fn format_str_with_regex(str_to_format: String) {
    let re = regex::Regex::new(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)").expect("Unable to create regex pattern");
    for field in re.find_iter(&str_to_format) {
        println!("{:?}: {}", field, field.as_str());    
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3cb2375fd2640f96b27e60e56b995065